# Using Darktable, how to batch convert from RAW to another supported format

Tags: raw, darktable, batch, tiff, export

I've notice on other answers there are ways to use the History Stack in Darktable to batch convert a bunch of RAW images. However, since I really only want to use Darktable to export a lot of RAW images, for my purposes into 8-bit uncompressed TIFF's, I wondered if this is possible somehow?

Answer (score 2):

After some exploration, it is actually quite straight-forward. The process can be adapted for your own conversion requirements, but I wanted 8-bit TIFF - the reason why is irrelevant.

1. Open up 'Storage Options' in 'lighttable' section of Darktable, set the required settings. For me, TIFF, 8-bit, uncompressed. Set the desired path for file export to disk, and conflict options.

[image: Storage Options Settings]

2. Select all of the images you wish to export / convert. Use CTRL and LMB to multiple-select RAW images. For this test, I used the same RAW image with different filenames (1300875350_fuji-x100-dscf5613.RAF, 2300875350_fuji-x100-dscf5613.RAF, 3300875350_fuji-x100-dscf5613.RAF). Sadly, you can't see this very well on the screenshot, but I hope the reader understands the strategy.

[image: Custom Select Images For Export]

3. Alternatively, use the SELECT ALL option near the top-right of lightable UI.

[image: Quick And Dirty Select All Option For Export]

4. Click the EXPORT button in 'Storage Options' - see Step 1 above. Darktable will then export the files in TIFF (or whatever) format.

[image: The Result On Disk]

I hope this helps some others like me who want to convert a whole bunch of files from RAW to some other format. Bravo!

Comment: This reads like an x→y question. What is the purpose for which you want to convert raw image files to 8-bit TIFFs? No matter how you do it, the TIFFs will not be able to contain as much information as the raw files.

Comment: The resulting format doesn't matter. This is about the process. I just needed TIFFs, and lots of them.

Comment: Why do you think you need TIFFs? And why only 8-bit TIFFs?

Comment: Please see:[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/348605)